# CLR 2.0 library and XBAP

Tags: .net, wpf, xbap

i used the app.config to set up legacy runtime activation policy for runtime 2.0 in a wpf Desktop application.

That worked properly.

Now i have a wpf browser application (XBAP) and i also set up the app.config.

This doesn't work.

It still Shows the error that assembly could not be loaded without additional config. Just as if the app.config wouldn't be there.

Is there an extra treatment for 2.0 libs and XBAP applications?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After refining my search i found the answer here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92d65e67-d13f-45a0-8b49-2909dde6f555/xbap-mixed-mode-assembly-unable-to-load-in-net-40?forum=wpfprerelease

Conclusion:

- the Startup element of the app.config is ignored by xbap (as officially documented)
- you Need to set the v2 legacy mode in code (as described in the link above)
  (which is not an official solution)

That's it.